# Accessing a variable declared in fla from as file

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

On the stage I have a movieclip by the name of `rect_mc`. Inside it have have a MovieClip `sqaure_mc`.

In the time line that I get when I double click on `rect_mc` (timeline of `rect_mc`) I have written the following code

```
var width1:Number;
width1 = sqaure_mc.width;
```

How can I access `width1` from the document class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Export your square_mc for ActionScript and define a class. Then in this class, define your variables.

```
package
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;

    public class SquareMC extends MovieClip
    {
        public var width1:Number;

        public function SquareMC()
        {
            width1 = width;
        }
    }
}
```

The properties defined within this will be accessible from the document class via:

```
rect_mc.square_mc.width1;
```

Comment: The thing that I want to is access the variable declared there.In the timeline of rect_mc. Just for the sake of a example only I choose the width of movieclip. My doubt is how can access a variable declared inside the timeline of rect_mc. It could be any variable.Anyway thanks for replying.

Comment: If you define anything within `square_mc` then it's accessible via `square_mc.rect_mc.your_var`.

Comment: Sorry to ask you once again . The square_mc is inside the rect_mc. I have written

Comment: I will post the question once again.

Comment: Sorry, should have looked into that one a bit more.